# Favicon on gmail has changed from the envelope to a black gun. How do i change it back and why did it change?

Tags: gmail

I think my gmail account might have been hacked because I've recently noticed a change in the favicon displayed in the url and the tab, when I logged onto my gmail account. It used to be the common red and white envelope and now it's a black gun.

Can anyone tell if this is enough to conclude that my account has been hacked or tampered with? I know someone that would be capable and most probably willing to cause problems to my account among other things. This would be my opsessive ex who's best friend is a hacker. Can anyone help? I need to know if someone has reigns to my computer.

And how do I change the favicon back to its orginial image? The black gun really bothers me.

Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: Any particular browser?

Comment: Or all browsers?

Answer (score 4):

People can't `hack` your account like that (You watch way too much TV/movies :P). Its just not possible. Your browser might have gone FUBAR. Clear your cache, cookies, and so on. (Or try gmail with private mode (firefox: ctrl+shift+p, chrome: ctrl+shift+n)).
Other way to go is deleting your application data for the given browser ... but thats too radical in such problem. So give the first one a try.

Answer (score 1):

Iam not pro in these details.... But may this help you. I had the same prob for few months and believe me, i too was irritated since no solution worked. But recently i realised that **when i change the *themes* in *settings tab* the favicon reverted back**. Give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of straying into completely non-technical territory, when it comes to hacking an ex ... or even current ... spouse's computer the preferred method according to media accounts I've seen is to install a key logger or similar tool on the spouse's system. I have a friend who's husband did that to her.

It requires physical access to the computer but frankly that's probably a lot easier than most people believe.

If you're worried, then either dig up your own "hacker friend" and have them check your hard drive for spyware or just format and reinstall everything from the optical install media.

Comment: Nope... doesn't require physical access to the computer.  Keyloggers can be installed remotely.  (It is *easier* to do with physical access, but remote installation can definitely occur.)